# How do I count occurrences of a list of strings and output them to a new file?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, io

I have been given three '.txt' files.

The first is a list of words. 
The second is a document to search.
The third is a blank document that will have my output written to it.

I'm supposed to take each word in the first file, search the second file and print the number of occurrences in the third file as "wordX = numOccurences."

I've got a good function that will return the wordCount, and it returns it correctly for the first word, but then I get a zero for all the remaining words.

I've tried to dereference everything, and I think I've come to a standstill. There's something wrong with the "pointer talk."

I have yet to start outputting the words to a new file, but that printf statement should be a print to file statement in append mode.  Easy enough.

Here is the working wordCount function - it works if I just give it a single word, like "testing," but if I give it an array I want to iterate through, it just returns 0.

```
int countWord(char* filePath, char* word){  //Not mine. This is a working prototype function from SO, returns word count of particular word
FILE *fp;
int count = 0;
int ch, len;

if(NULL==(fp=fopen(filePath, "r")))
    return -1;
len = strlen(word);
for(;;){
    int i;
    if(EOF==(ch=fgetc(fp))) break;
    if((char)ch != *word) continue;
    for(i=1;i<len;++i){
        if(EOF==(ch = fgetc(fp))) goto end;
        if((char)ch != word[i]){
            fseek(fp, 1-i, SEEK_CUR);
            goto next;
        }
    }
    ++count;
    next: ;
}
end:
fclose(fp);
return count;
}
```

This is my part of the program, trying to call the function while the loop gets all the words from the first file.  The loop IS grabbing the words, because it prints them, but wordCount isn't accepting anything beyond the first word.

```
int main(){     


FILE *ptr_file;

char words[100];

ptr_file = fopen("searchWords.txt", "r");
if(!ptr_file)
  return -1;

while( fgets(words, 100, ptr_file)!=NULL )
 { 
   int wordCount = 0;

   char key[100] = &*words;
   wordCount = countWord("document.txt", words);
   printf("%s = %d\n", words, wordCount);  

 } 


  fclose(ptr_file);

  return 0;
```

}

Comment: Show `countWord` function..problem seems there

Comment: edited to show the function

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` reads `\n` too.That is the problem. To quote

> A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string copied to str.

To solve this, change it

```
while( fgets(words, 100, ptr_file)!=NULL )
{
    int len = strlen(words);
    words[len-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Nitpicking: `if (words[len-1] == '\n')`

Answer (score 0):

An immediate problem: `fgets` doesn't strip end-of-line from the string, so whatever you pass to `countWord` has an embedded newline.